# Hosting many SSL sites on Azure using a wildcard certificate with MVC

Tags: ssl, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, wildcard-subdomain, hostheaders

The following application currently runs on a Windows 2008 R2 server that I'm attempting to migrate to Azure:

**Part 1**

First I have the following ASP.NET MVC site that routes customers based on the first part of the DNS name:

```
https://customer1.myAzureSite.com

https://customer2.myAzureSite.com

https://customer3.myAzureSite.com

...

https://customerN.myAzureSite.com
```

**Part 2**

Then, I also have a different IIS website that is used for enrolling/signing up only

```
https://enroll.myAzureSite.com
```

**Part 3**

This application uses SOA, and there is another site for the businesslayer:

```
https://BusinessLayer.myAzureSite.com
```

**Work done so far**

I'm planning on using the "sites" tag in the config file to set up two sites.  I plan on using IIS host headers to catch the "enroll" and "businesslayer" subdomains.  I have a certificate with the following subject name `*.myAzureSite.com`

**Question:**

How do I properly configure my deployment (from an Azure perspective) so that all host headers go to my MVC application, and only one goes to "enroll", and another to "businesslayer"

**Question:**

Will this work correctly over SSL?

What [comparable](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true) configuration needs to be done?

Answer (score 4):

I'll start with the easy part, your wildcard SSL certificate should be fine for these sites.  You'll just need to make sure that you add a https endpoint to your role and select the appropriate certificate.

From what I can see, you'll need three sites defined in your service definition.  First the default one while will be your MVC site.  Then one each for your business and enroll sites.  Your sites section might look something like this:

```
 <Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="mvchttp" endpointName="http" />
      <Binding name="mvchttps" endpointName="https" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Enroll" physicalDirectory="\enroll...">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="mvchttp" endpointName="http" hostHeader = "enroll.MyAzureSite.Com" />
      <Binding name="mvchttps" endpointName="https" hostHeader = "enroll.MyAzureSite.Com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="BusinessLayer" physicalDirectory="\BusinessLayer...">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="mvchttp" endpointName="http" hostHeader = "BusinessLayer.MyAzureSite.Com" />
      <Binding name="mvchttps" endpointName="https" hostHeader = "BusinessLayer.MyAzureSite.Com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that deploying multiple sites to a web role has recently been made much easier with the help of the Windows Azure Accelerator for web roles - more info at http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/

Comment: fyi this is now deprecated, see https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-accelerator-webroles