# How do I configure Diagnostics when many websites are on the same Azure WebRole?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I'm working an Azure Web role with many websites [as described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433469/hosting-many-ssl-sites-on-azure-using-a-wildcard-certificate-with-mvc)  How should I configure the Diagnostics for this server to that I can log errors and events from not just the primary website but all websites in the deployment / role.

Comment: If all these sites are deployed on Azure diagnostic logging should work for all. Are you facing any problem doing it or am i missing some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagnostics for individual web sites are logged using the role name, role instance name and (where appropriate) the IIS service ID - so the standard Azure diagnostics should work without needing to do any further work.